# how to create rounded beveled inset

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm just getting started (2 weeks) with blender and have succeeded in creating everything I set out to create using guides and tutorials, but I am stuck on my current challenge. I am trying to model an action figure toy mini gun.
[image]

I've tried insetting and bevelling (ctrl-b and shift-ctrl-b) but never get the required result. It is meant for 3d-printing so it should look like the final result after applying the subdivision modifier.
I tried following along with this trash can model, but without voice-over, I can't seem to get the same result. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqnHiRfZ2CU

This is what I am starting from.
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated very much to continue my learning journey.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a 16 vertex cylinder instead of 8 and inset and extrude inwards these faces:

[image]